# How to replace first character only for matched regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
regOpenTags = new RegExp("<+[a-zA-Z]", "g");
```

matches html opening tags (e.g. `<body>`) without matching closing tags (e.g. `</body>`). 
I'd like to replace the first character of matched tags which is `<`, but doing

```
parsedString = string.replace(regOpenTags, '');
```

would replace also the first letter. In other words, when using `replace()` on a string containing `<body>`, I'd prefer to get `body>` instead of `ody>`.

How can I use the `replace()` method or regex to achieve this?

Comment: You're positively looking for a positive look ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **Positive Lookahead** to achieve this.

```
regOpenTags = new RegExp("<(?=[a-z])", "gi");
```

Regular expression

```
<             '<'
(?=           look ahead to see if there is:
 [a-z]        any character of: 'a' to 'z'
)             end of look-ahead
```

See working [`demo`](https://eval.in/138868)

Another way of using a Positive Lookahead with **negation**.

```
regOpenTags = new RegExp("<(?=[^/])", "g");
```